# Не удается сделать связь между таблицами

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

В базе данных есть две таблицы, которые нужно связать между собой. Таблицы: учитель, должность учителя.

Связь планировал сделать по столбцам Position и Name, где TeacherPosition представляла бы собой зависимую таблицу.

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;    
CREATE TABLE Teacher(
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        Name NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null,
        Surname NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null,
        Position NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null
    )
CREATE TABLE TeacherPosition(
    Name NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Salary INT DEFAULT null,
    FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES Teacher (Position)
)
```

Однако получаю ошибку

> В таблице "Teacher", на которую имеются ссылки, отсутствуют первичные
> или потенциальные ключи, соответствующие списку ссылающихся столбцов
> во внешнем ключе "FK__TeacherPos__Name__08EA5793".

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой пост и предоставьте DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в T-SQL без референции на данный момент.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky обновил, добавил только create database. Изначально создается пустая база данных, вот в чем проблема и он мне выдает такую ошибку, хотя пишу голый запрос с созданием, без значений и прочего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам концептуальный пример с данными.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.child;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.parent;

CREATE TABLE dbo.parent (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [State] CHAR(2));
CREATE TABLE dbo.child (
   ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   , ParentID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.parent(ID)
   , City VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.parent ([State])
VALUES ('FL')
   , ('TX');

INSERT INTO dbo.child (ParentID, City)
VALUES (1, 'Miami')
   , (1, 'Fort Lauderdale')
   , (2, 'Austin')
   , (2, 'Dallas');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM dbo.parent;
SELECT * FROM dbo.child;
```

**SQL для вашего конкретного случая**

Первичный ключ родительской таблицы распространяется как внешний ключ на дочернюю таблицу. Это не может быть просто какой-то произвольный столбец, используемый для внешнего ключа.

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher(
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        Name NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null,
        Surname NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null,
        Position NVARCHAR(20) DEFAULT null
    )
CREATE TABLE TeacherPosition(
    Name NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Salary INT DEFAULT null,
    Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Teacher(ID)
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, после прочтения пришлось заново читать теорию, разобрался в чем был не прав